# Inner Joining Tables with 2 different variables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is an MVC5 with EF6 Identity Web Application

The Administrator column that you can see from my cshtml page is IssuedTo. Issueto is linked to id in my AspNetUsers.

I'm trying to display the name of what the IssueTo is pointing at so if it's 1 it should display Andy Domagas instead of 1.

[image]
[image]

I tried doing what I did for User by creating a virtual ApplicationUser property for IssuedTo instead of User. I did this by adding `[ForeignKey("IssuedTo")] public virtual ApplicationUser assignedAdmin{ get; set; }` and then in my View used `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssuedUser.LastName)` but I get **Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths**.

IdentityModel.cs(ApplicationUser) (Added TicketsIssuedTo Collection)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>, IRole<int>
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public ApplicationRole(string name, string description)
            : this(name)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
        }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> TicketsIssuedTo { get; set; }




    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext
        : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.IssuedUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.TicketsIssuedTo)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.IssueID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }


        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }


    }



    public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationUserStore()
            : this(new IdentityDbContext())
        {
            base.DisposeContext = true;
        }

        public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }


    public class ApplicationRoleStore
    : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>,
    IQueryableRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>,
    IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>, IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationRoleStore()
            : base(new IdentityDbContext())
        {
            base.DisposeContext = true;
        }

        public ApplicationRoleStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Ticket.cs (Added IssuedID and IssuedUser )

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int? TicketID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the Administrator")]
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public int Author { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }  
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int IssueID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IssueID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser IssuedUser { get; set; }

}
```

**It's giving me too much of a headache to fix this so my question is are there any other options to do this?**

Can I use a Linq statement in my TicketController Index method and 
SELECT FirstName LastName etc. INNER JOIN User Table.id with Ticket Table.Administrator(IssuedTo) ??

**Updated code after Gert's suggestion to use FluentAPI** IdentityModel.cs (Inside OnModelCreating method)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.IssuedUser)
    .WithMany(u => u.TicketsIssuedTo)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.IssueID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 }
```

**Error on u**

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because
>   some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible
>   to the delegate return type   RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem

**Error on TicketsIssuedTo**

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
>   **RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.ApplicationUser** to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
>   **RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.Ticket**. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

You can only solve this by fluent mapping, because you need to remove cascaded delete from one foreign key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.IssuedUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.TicketsIssuedTo)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.IssueID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This is in the `OnModelCreating` override in your `DbContext` subclass.

But you've got...

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> TicketsIssuedTo { get; set; }
```

... that should be:

```
public virtual ICollection<Ticket> TicketsIssuedTo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Inside my ` public class ApplicationDbContext` I have  `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` and `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();`(Because I tried to remove cascaded delete) Should I also remove them?

Comment: I wouldn't remove that convention. Cascaded delete can give a huge performance boost. I'd remove cascaded delete only where it isn't desired.

Comment: I don't think you need a `.` at the end of `modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>() Also I'm getting a few errors and I've updated it in my question.

Comment: Now it's absolutely unclear to me what you did. What does your *current* `Ticket` class look like? You show it two times, both with different added properties. And which FK caused the exception?

Comment: Apologies! I've been trying to fix it myself and changed some of the code. I've updated the code in the question! I believe it's ` FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Tickets_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserID'`

Comment: I'm still having the same error `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Tickets_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserID' on table 'Tickets' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`